# Way to apply HTML code to each element of php array

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, foreach

I'm building a gallery application and I've been having Issues finding out If there Is a way I can put HTML around each PHP array value In my case images,
I believe that If I echo It I'll get the values as text. I don't want to echo the values as text any options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some code for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the following may be of some help, If you want to display the images in HTML you could use something like the following.

```
$images = array(
   "1" => "image1.png",
   "2" => "image2.jpeg",
   "3" => "image3.gif"
);

foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
   echo "<img src=\"{$image}\" alt=\"image {$key}\"/>";
}
```

and if you want to place the images inside HTML and back into your array you can use the following.

```
$images = array(
   "1" => "image1.png",
   "2" => "image2.jpeg",
   "3" => "image3.gif"
);

foreach ($images as $key => $val) {
   $images[$key] = "<img src=\"{$val}\" alt=\"image {$key}\"/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is just a "coders block", but it's very simple. grab the array, iterate it, wrap the output of each array element in a div and echo it back to the requesting page.

```
foreach($array as $item):
    echo '<div>', $item ,'</div>';
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

You seem to be looking for `array_walk`:

> ```
> bool array_walk(array &$Input, callable $Fn [, mixed $extra = null ])
>
> Applies the user-defined function Fn to 
> each element of the array Input, optionally
> passing it the user-specified object $extra.
> ```

This is an example of wrapping every element of the array between two user-specified values.

```
<?php
    $arry = array(
        'pear',
        'orange',
        'banana',
    );

    array_walk($arry, function(&$item, $key, $data) {
        $item = $data['before'].$item.$data['after'];
    }, array(
        'before'    => 'this is a ',
        'after'     => ' squash.',
    ));

    print_r($arry);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is a pear squash.
    [1] => this is a orange squash.
    [2] => this is a banana squash.
)
```

## Option 2

Another option could be that of using `preg_replace_callback` to perform a bulk replace on each element. This allows greater flexibility both in specifying what to replace, and how to replace it:

```
<?php
    $arry = array(
        'pear squash',
        'squishy orange',
        'squoshed banana',
    );

    // FIRST - wrap everything in double round brackets

    $arry = preg_replace_callback('/^.*$/', function($matches){

        return "(($matches[0]))";

    }, $arry);

    // SECOND - convert anything like "SQUASH" (but with whatever letter instead
    // of the "A" - to "juice":

    $arry = preg_replace_callback('/(.*)squ(.)sh(.*)/', function($matches){

        // $matches[2] contains the whatever letter.
        return $matches[1].'juice'.$matches[3];

    }, $arry);

    print_r($arry);
```

returns now

```
Array
(
    [0] => ((pear juice))
    [1] => ((juicey orange))
    [2] => ((juiceed banana))
)
```